# Making link to go somewhere else than its default href

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, query-string

I want to grab the link text and append it to the URL and open the new URL with querystring added Onclick of the Original Link..How do I get the link text using javascript or jquery?

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/search.aspx?kwd=" onClick="location.href='http://mysite.com/search.aspx?kwd='+ Grab text 'kangaroo' and append here as QueryString>Kangaroo</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current anchor through `this`.  The text can be then had through `this.innerHTML`.

Something like this...

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/search.aspx?kwd=" onClick="location.href='http://mysite.com/search.aspx?kwd='+ this.innerHTML; return false;">Kangaroo</a>
```

Comment: it works perfect but i ran into a problem there are Link Text like more than two words Like "Heart Health" so when it gets addedit has to look like http://mysite.com/search.aspx?kwd=Heart%20Health..How do you ad that %20in between? Also no spaces, it has to be trimmed?

Comment: @Gasim `encodeURIComponent` is already setup to make the necessary replacements, also try using the MDN docs, w3schools is inferior: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: yeah I just realized it. So, removed it to not to confuse him :) Thank you for the information. I always google'd something and first thing that came up was always w3schools. Now going to use MDN

Comment: @T. Stone How do you trim what was returned by this.innerHTML to get rid of spaces?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.your-url').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location= $(this).attr('href') + encodeURIComponent($(this).text());
});
```

I noticed that none of the other answers were encoding the text in the link to be a query-string parameter.

Inline (like your example) would look like this:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/search.aspx?kwd=" onClick="location.href = this.href + encodeURIComponent($.trim($(this).text()))">Kangaroo</a>
```

`return false` should be unnecessary because once you change the `location` object scripts stop running and the page changes.

**UPDATE**

You can use `$.trim()` to:

> Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/*

Comment: kwd=%26nbsp%3BHeart%20Health...i need to get rid of the space?? How do i do that?

Comment: @AnjuThapa jQuery has the `$.trim()` method to remove excess white-space. I **updated** my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To send the page to the link's `href + text` when clicked, this should work:

```
$("a").click(function(){
     location.href = $(this).attr("href") + $(this).text();
     return false;
});
```

But why not just set the hrefs correctly when the page loads, and get rid of all these `onclick` handlers altogether?

```
$("a").each(function(i, el) {
     var $el = $(el);
     $el.attr("href", $el.attr("href") + encodeURI($el.text()));
});
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood his question. I believe he wants his final onclick link to look like: `location.href='http://mysite.com/search.aspx?kwd=kangaroo'`

Comment: How do you grab kangaroo value? that was my problem. I can't just add to the url as it is dynamic

Comment: innerHTML in plain JS. $.text() in jquery

Comment: @AnjuThapa - my first answer was a major fail - see my edit.  My apologies.

Comment: @AnjuThapa - glad to hear it.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery example:

```
$('a.link').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        href = $this.attr('href');

    window.location = href + encodeURIComponent($this.text());
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4bCBt/)

Comment: oops. we wrote it at the same time. I always put e.preventDefault() before anything else. You put it after everything else. What is the difference?

Comment: Not much, so long as it's called in the function body

Comment: @Gasim Within a jQuery event handler, `return false;` is the same as `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`. And no there isn't a difference as to when `event.preventDefault()` is called within the event handler.

Comment: cat=%26nbsp%3BHeart%20Health how do i get rid of %26nbsp%3B which is a space i think?

Comment: @AnjuThapa, you are getting that because you are using innerHtml not my example most likely

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.your-url').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  url = $(this).attr('href') + $(this).text();
  location.href = url;

});
```